# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, pong

i have a bouncing ball, and i tried to make so when it bounces once, the speed gets higher.

In my ball class, i have a `float speed;`

and i initialized it:
`public ball(float speed)
speed = 1f;`

I have a method for my ball movement, that looks like this:

```
public void BallMovement()
{
    if (movingUp) { ballRect.Y -= speed; }//Error
    if (!movingUp) {  ballRect.Y += speed; }//Error
    if (movingLeft) {  ballRect.X -= speed; }//Error
    if (!movingLeft) {  ballRect.X += speed; }//Error

    if (ballPosition.Y < 85)
    {
        movingUp = false;
    }
    if (ballPosition.Y >= 480)
    {
        movingUp = true;
    }
```

I then add this in the update method: `BallMovement();`

It worked before i tried to use the speed variable, it won't compile because of this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'.An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed needs to be float. If you want to keep the speed as a float, you could create your own rectangle structure. You could do something like this:

```
        public struct RectangleF
    {
        float w = 0;
        float h = 0;
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;

        public float Height
        {
            get { return h; }
            set { h = value; }
        }

        //put Width, X, and Y properties here

        public RectangleF(float width, float height, float X, float Y)
        {
            w = width;
            h = height;
            x = X;
            y = Y;
        }

        public bool Intersects(Rectangle refRectangle)
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);
            if (rec.Intersects(refRectangle)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

The intersection checking won't be absolutely perfect, but at least your rectangle's X and Y could have 0.5 added on to them. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `speed` is declared as type `float`.

You can do the math by converting speed from float to integer like this:

```
public void BallMovement()
{
    int speedInt = Convert.Int32(speed);

    if (movingUp) { ballRect.Y -= speedInt; }
    if (!movingUp) {  ballRect.Y += speedInt; }
    if (movingLeft) {  ballRect.X -= speedInt; }
    if (!movingLeft) {  ballRect.X += speedInt; }

    if (ballPosition.Y < 85)
    {
        movingUp = false;
    }
    if (ballPosition.Y >= 480)
    {
        movingUp = true;
    }
    ....
```

On the other hand, if you want the compiler to convert it for you (multiple times), you could cast each of the occasions where you reference `speed` with `(int)speed`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to subtract a float value (ex: 1.223488) from an int (ex: 12);  You can't do this.  Either convert (cast) both values to floats, or convert (cast) both values to ints:

```
 if (movingUp) { ballRect.Y -= (int)speed; }//Error
```

The error is basically saying "We can't automatically convert this for you (implicit), but you can convert it yourself (explicit)."  I'd check out the MSDN article on type casting:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: But i have a method that makes the speed increase by 0.5 when collides, that messes up the collision :/

Answer (score 1):

Does the `speed` needs to be `float`? If not you could make

```
int speed;
```

Or use a explicit cast

```
if (movingUp) { ballRect.Y -= (int)speed; }// No Error
```